# Separating lookup tables used by multiple databases

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I have two databases that are using same lookup tables (including country, state, language-like tables). Currently, these lookup tables are in one of the databases.

Should I store these lookup tables in a separate third database?
Would separating them bring any burden during joins?

I do a search on this but I found intra-database issues only.

Answer (score 1):

There is no additional complication with cross-database joins.

Comment: What is your comment on separating lookup tables into another database/schema?

Comment: A same common database container user login, country, state, language that is used by more than one database makes a lot of sense. It also simplifies access control if there is an application per database (with unique application user), and the common bits is a restricted grant to each application user.

Answer (score 0):

If you do separate the lookup tables into a separate `DATABASE`, then be sure to `GRANT` `SELECT` access to anyone needing to reach them.

Normally, a user or application would be provided with a single-db access something like

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_foo.* TO app_foo@... IDENTIFIED BY ...;
```

This would also need

```
GRANT SELECT on Lookups.* TO app_foo@...;
```

and the accessing would be something like

```
SELECT some_table.blah, Lookups.Countries.country_name
     FROM some_table     -- I'm assuming you are 'in' `db_foo`
     JOIN Lookups.Countries
       ON some_table.country_id = Lookups.Countries.id
```

or

```
SELECT t.blah, c.country_name
     FROM some_table  AS t
     JOIN Lookups.Countries  AS c
       ON t.country_id = c.id
```